# Split an array into groups based on the size & return 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have seen the solutions using push and slice but I wanted to achieve this using nested loops. When the number of elements in array are divisible by size, this code works but it doesn't work for other cases.

```
let arr2d = [];

function breakIt(arr, size){
  if(arr.length % size === 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
     arr2d[i] = new Array(size);
    } 

    console.log(arr2d);
    let increm = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < (arr.length/size); i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < size; j++){
        arr2d[i][j] = arr[increm];
        increm++;
        //console.log(arr2d[i][j]);
        }
    }
   } else {
     console.log('Odd number of elements in arr');
   }

  console.log(arr2d);
}

breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3);
breakIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2);

//breakIt([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)should return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result and what not work.

Comment: breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3);
breakIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2);
breakIt([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)should return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
The code gives me desired result when the function is called with first three but doesnt work with the last one.

Comment: please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with one loop as well:

#### Logic:

- Loop over data.
- Create 2 arrays,

  - `result` to have final output
  - `temp` to hold intermediate value
- If number of elements are pushed in `temp`, you can clone and push cloned data in result. You will also have to do it after loop ends for any trailing values.

```js
function breakIt(data, len) {
  const result = [];
  let temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i % len === 0 && i > 0) {
      result.push(temp.slice());
      temp = [];
    }
    temp.push(data[i])
  }
  result.push(temp)
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
breakIt(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3);
breakIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2);
breakIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4);
```